# Why can't you use dependency injection with an httphandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, httphandler

I have an httphandler like this:

```
public class MyProxy : IHttpHandler
{
    public MyProxy() { }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I want to be able to inject a service (KeyVaultService) so I can move some app settings that are sitting in the web.config to the key vault. However, when I inject the KeyVaultService the MyProxy is no longer hit. I'm assuming this is how httpHandlers work, so why is this and is there some way round this (both generally and specifically for a KeyVaultService)? For this case could I create SecretClient?

Comment: `IHttpHandler` is from the older part of ASP.NET which predates the built-in dependency injection system introduced in ASP.NET Core. That said, you can get DI working with (with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` WebForms and ASP.NET MVC using libraries like (disclaimer: I wrote this): https://github.com/Jehoel/AspNetDependencyInjection

Comment: Hmm....this is change to our platform, and as always timing is of the essence, so I suspect I can't suddenly try and bring this in. I will have to try a workaround route. I feel another question coming soon if I don't get SecretClient working

Comment: You know, you don't **have** to use a platform-integrated DI - you could always have your own mini factory for `KeyVaultService`.

Comment: @Dai - not sure I understand. Could you give an example please?